# In TBB, is there a way to find out if there is an existing task scheduler?

Tags: initialization, scheduled-tasks, intel, tbb

In Threading Building Blocks (TBB), if I initialize 2 task schedulers within the same scope, the argument of the second initialization will be ignored unless the argument of the first initialization is deferred. In order to avoid any conflicts, I would like to find out if a task scheduler has been initialized earlier in my program. Is there a way to do it? If so, what was the argument to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to consider `tbb::this_task_arena::current_thread_index()` and `tbb::this_task_arena::max_concurrency()` functions.

The `tbb::this_task_arena::current_thread_index()` function returns "`tbb::task_arena::not_initialized` if the thread has not yet initialized the task scheduler." ([documentation link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506359)).

If the task scheduler is already initialized you can obtain the requested number of threads with the `tbb::this_task_arena::max_concurrency()` function. However, you cannot get the stack size used during the previous task scheduler initialization.